# AWS Codebuild knows my secret values, but won't inject them into my commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-secrets-manager

I have a situation where I have a secret `important_secret` stored in secrets manager with a secret value of

```
{
    "tf_cloud_token": "super_secret"
}
```

In the codebuild console, I have linked it up:
[image]

In my buildspec, I have:

```
{
  "version": 0.2,
  "env": {
    "variables": {},
    "secrets-manager": {
      "SECRET_TF_CLOUD_TOKEN": "important_secret:tf_cloud_token",
    },
    "git-credential-helper": "yes"
  },
  "phases": {
    "build": {
      "commands": [
        "printf 'blah \"$SECRET_TF_CLOUD_TOKEN\"' > ~/.terraformrc",
        "more ~/.terraformrc",
        ...
```

But it will just log `blah "$SECRET_TF_CLOUD_TOKEN"`.

However, when I change it to:

```
    ...
    "commands": [
      "printf 'blah \"super_secret\"' > ~/.terraformrc",
      "more ~/.terraformrc"
      ...
```

It'll log `blah "***"`.

Therefore, it definitely knows about my secret value but it's just not injecting it properly.

How do I get it to use the `SECRET_TF_CLOUD_TOKEN` environment variable I have prepared for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the string interpolation: `"echo blah \"$SECRET_TF_CLOUD_TOKEN\" > ~/.terraformrc"`

```sh
SECRET_TF_CLOUD_TOKEN="my-secret"

echo blah \"$SECRET_TF_CLOUD_TOKEN\" > ~/.terraformrc

cat ~/.terraformrc
# -> blah "my-secret"
```